Cant replace a connection string in Azure yaml pipeline with Variable Substitution
Im building a release pipeline in Azure Devops. In yaml. Need to deploy to two environments so far
I also have a build pipeline before producing an artifact.
This is setup with msbuild parameters like this:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: "Build solution"
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:IsTransformWebConfigDisabled=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebPackage.zip" /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True'
    platform: 'any cpu'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

I am building with configuration: Release
Because I am deploying to a Dev environment I don´t want to the xml transformation to happen in the build because it should use its default connection string.
So in my deploy to Production I added this task
variables:
   someBool: "true"
   connectionStrings:ReviewDb: "server=prod;database=Review;user id=***;password='****"
   RecipeDb: "server=Prod;database=Recipe2014;user id=***;password=****"
   IISWebSiteName: 'MySite'
 strategy: 
   runOnce:
      deploy:
       steps:
           - checkout: none

           - download: 'reviewMainCI'
             name: 'DownloadBuildArtifacts'
             displayName:  'Download Build Artifacts'
             artifact: 'WebPackage'
           

           # Set right connectionstring for production
           - task: FileTransform@2
             inputs:
               folderPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\**\*.zip'
               xmlTargetFiles: '**\Web.config'
               enableXmlTransform: false

I added the someBool in the appsetting part of the webconfig and it gets replaced easily but the two connectionstrings does not change
log from the step in Azure
Path = C:\azagent\A2\_work\1\reviewMainCI\WebPackage\WebPackage.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 8881030

Everything is Ok

Folders: 3
Files: 77
Size:       22192856
Compressed: 8881030

##[error]Unable to apply transformation for the given package - Changes are already present in the package.
Initiated variable substitution in config file : C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_5072113810855332\Content\D_C\a\1\s\MyProject.Review\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config
Processing substitution for xml node : appSettings
Updating value for key= someBool with token value: CONFIG_FILE_SETTINGS_TOKEN(someBool)
Processing substitution for xml node : connectionStrings
Config file : C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_5072113810855332\Content\D_C\a\1\s\MyProject.Review\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Web.config updated.
XML variable substitution applied successfully.
Finishing: FileTransform

Also there is this error that changes has been applied already. That why I tried to delete the Web.Release.config and disable it in the build.
Tried different naming of the connection strings but none of these two does the trick
